# ViewPager2 without Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I have an application and I need to realize a behavior where I have an XML layout that I need to apply for every ViewPager2 page NOT USING FRAGMENTS. Is there an opportunity?

I have an ArrayList and regarding his size I need to create the same amount of pages in ViewPager2 and fill every page with an info in my array. There can be plenty of pages, that's why I don't want to create a fragment for every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ViewPager2`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) is essentially a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView) wrapper that adds layout and touch handling to account for items that have size of a page (fill entire widgets size).

[`setAdapter(RecyclerView.Adapter adapter)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)) lets you use any recycler view adapter. There was never a requirement to use a `FragmentStateAdapter`.

So just implement a normal recycler view adapter and your pages will be displayed using view holders (that are created using your XML layout).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response. You are definitely right and the guy helped me a lot with this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y946tVSRQmc&ab_channel=tutorialsEU-Android)